# Need add field to existed class model

Tags: django, django-models

I need to change ArticleModel in django-wiki app. Actually add few fields to Model. What solution can I use? 
I read about `Model.add_to_class` but not understand where put this code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you can just change the model.py file, then run `python manage.py makemigrations` then `syncdb` command.

You can also (likely not recommended, but works for me), change the model.py file then manually change the database table with SQL commands.

Comment: but with this we will break backward compatibility

Comment: why would it break backward compatibility?  are you wanting to remove fields?

Comment: because this is third part app, i need fork first